# Could crystals grow on living things?

Tags: biology, magic, creature-design, biochemistry, avian

A friend and I are creating a magical bird that eats gemstones then uses them to form a thin coat of crystal armor over its body. Is there any way for this bird (or any living thing) to actually have crystals growing on its body? I kind of want this ability to make scientific sense, but explanations that involve magic are okay too.

Comment: Technically I think chitin is crystalline in structure. Might not be exactly what you’re envisioning though.

Comment: @JoeBloggs I didn't think of that! Unfortunately, it's not really what I was looking for, but thank you anyways!

Comment: Most organisms use composites because they are stronger and way way easier to make biologically than a pure crystal.

Comment: Go with sexual selection, organisms do some truly absurd and self destructive things in the name of attracting a mate.

Comment: @John: I recently heard something like “Your body is just a very complicated walking advertisement for your gametes” and it stuck with me

Comment: I prefer "sometimes a chicken is just an eggs way of making another egg."

Comment: This is pretty strange for a *bird* to do this, given the weight involved, and the question arises: does it need to *eat* the gems and secrete the crystals or is using gems to produce the armor enough?

Comment: Related scifi question about ["crystal foxes"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199362/how-can-the-crystal-foxes-in-the-last-jedi-be-living) in Star Wars.

Comment: You've clearly never suffered from gout!

Comment: Also note that crystals, in general, make bad armor - they break easily on impact. Diamonds, for instance, are extremely hard, but they can be cleaved (split) by a properly directed steel tool. Sapphire (aluminum oxide) is very hard and tough (for a crystal), but see https://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/testing-sapphire-how-tough-is-it-really-1262028 for a demo of what can happen with a strong (less-than-combat) impact.

Comment: Related question [on crystal ecosystem](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/126184/feasibility-of-a-crystal-ecosystem)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## It's known as [Biomineralization](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/scientifica/2012/867562/)

> Biomineralization is the formation of complexes containing inorganic
> materials by living organisms. This occurs in organs as diverse as
> bone, teeth, egg shells, and invertebrate exoskeletons. Calcium is
> a very “popular” biomineral, occurring for example, as phosphates in
> vertebrate skeletons and carbonates in mollusk shells. However,
> another important player is silicon. Silicon is the second most common
> element in the Earth’s crust after oxygen, and silica (silicon
> dioxide) is the most abundant compound in the earth’s crust.
> Biosilicification is the process by which inorganic silicon is
> incorporated into living organisms as silica, which occurs on the
> scale of gigatons. In practice this involves the condensation of
> orthosilicate Si(OH)4 into long polymers with the elimination of
> water.

In the case of stinging nettles, the stings are made of hollow [silica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide) spears containing formic acid:

[image]

<sub>*Attribution Wikipedia CCL. 2019.*</sub>

[Diatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom) (microscopic animals) make their own armour out of it:

[image]
<sub>*Attribution Unknown 2019*</sub>

In principle if your organisms were to make their armour from - instead of silicon dioxide - say aluminium oxide, then they would have a Saphire or Ruby armour, or with Beryllium compounded, Emerald. The colour/shade and luster would vary perhaps depending on the particular minerals available in the diet of your creatures.

The [Placoid scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_scale#Placoid_scales) of sharks (AKA dermal denticles) are made exactly like teeth, with a blood supply, [dentene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dentin) ([hydroxylapetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyapatite)), and hard enamel on the outside, acting to reduce drag, they're also very tough and have enabled shark species to survive for millions of years without changing:

[image]

<sub>*Attribution Wikipedia CCL. 2019.*</sub>

So, yes, it's possible, because it's already here. Adapt it to your needs as you see fit.

Comment: Note these examples are all composite glasses not crystals. Large pure crystals are really difficult and slow to make biologically.

Comment: @John I was tempted to create a protein based crystaline armour, but we still haven't quite nailed the large-scale properties.

Comment: You could expand this to include crustaceans and corals and I think it would add something. Oh, and then there are the species that glue crystals to their carapace rather than grow them to consider.

Comment: @The Nate I couldn't help myself, on reading "the species that glue crystals to their carapaces" I googled "kim kardashian's wedding ring"

Comment: they could also [eat butterflies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/126184/feasibility-of-a-crystal-ecosystem/126194#126194)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it would come with problems.

Disclaimer: I'm not a biologist.

There are a number of chemical solutions that can be used to "grow" crystals. It's even possible with nothing but salt and water, given good temperature control and environmental conditions. You could potentially accomplish that with something like sweat glands. Other types of crystal may require more exotic biological systems, but I don't see why they couldn't work in the right environment.

**Problems**:

Weight - crystal armor is going to be either fragile or heavy. On Earth, a bird would have a hard time flying with enough crystal of sufficient "toughness" to act as a good defense against predators.

Flexibility - Hard crystal is going to be solid, so it would have to either grow in many small pieces (more fragile, with more vulnerabilities) or in immobile "plates" that would make flexibility a challenge. (Like turtle shells)

Temperature control - sweat will be less effective at cooling the body, if it works at all. (depends on how much of the body is covered in crystal) The exact material of the crystal will determine how good of a conductor of heat it is, but it could either over-insulate the creature, or be overly-effective at dissipating it's body heat. The creature will need to account for that, one way or the other.

I'm sure there are other potential complications, but that's all that comes to mind for me.

Comment: In practical term, you've got a point, but maybe like sharksteeth it could re-grow. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can even grow crystals yourself: When you sweat, your body basically releases salt water on your skin. Once the water dries off, you are left with salt crystals. They are of course rather tiny and not exactly like an armor.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Matthias! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Comment: I think non-water-soluble crystals were intended. That's tricky, because basically everything is water-soluble, but it's kind of a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Crytals can grow on many things. you can do a crystal growing experiment and the crystals could grow on plants.im not sure if it's ever been tried before. you can try this with these links:
https://kitchenpantryscientist.com/crystalline-entities-growing-alum-crystals/

for crystals to grow in general:
Crystals often form in nature when liquids cool and start to harden. Certain molecules in the liquid gather together as they attempt to become stable. They do this in a uniform and repeating pattern that forms the crystal. In nature, crystals can form when liquid rock, called magma, cools.

It is possible for crystals to grow on living organisms in the right conditions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and if you drink enough Port to give yourself Gout then you can try it for yourself.

> The symptoms of gout are due to the formation of uric acid crystals in the joints and the body's response to them.

[All you wanted to know about Gout.](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/144827.php)

Comment: Pseudogout's more relevant here imo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, this is a bird. And if it flies, crystal shell is not the best, or even a plausable option.

**Fancy beak**

Crystal is heavy, not so flexible, brittle, and offers very little compared to that for a bird. One thing I can think of is a crystal beak.
Different feeding habits require different biological bodies. Maybe your bird eats minerals and breaks down different minerals, makes a coated crystal beak. So the beak is hard enough, durable enough, and can be used to eat more mineral.

Make sure your bird stores minerals and changes beaks like a snake shedding its skin, and we are good to go. Add talons to the equation and a bird with crystal beak and talons is here now. Fancy.

**Crystal feathers!**

Alternative is, aerodymanic crystal structure.
Crystal feathers! Yey! The bird will have thin crystal feathers arranged in a strategic way to maximize the flexibility and reduce the weight, create aerodynamy to help it fly fast.

**Diamond trex?**

Remember the first sentence? Yeah, things change for an ostrich. Or any bird prefer running really. An ostritch can afford to be heavier and can access to more ground resources if it does not need to fly.
Maybe a heavier, bulkier ostrich that relies more on muscles instead of dexterity can eat crystals and grow a magnificent crystal tail. Like a porcubine. Or a hedgehog. Kinda like a spiky dinasaour, running to their prey, stabbing them with lots of crystal needles, and knocking them over with weight and strength. An interlocking crystal plate armor around the bird can offer protection, can be used as a weapon and armor and a hunting method.

Make it tameble like a horse, and you can even add crystal armored knights riding crystal covered birds. Beautiful. Deadly.

There are crabs with solid shell, sea snails with mineral made shells, and there is a snail growing an iron armor around it. So, if you consider iron crystals good enough, there is a living animal doing exactly this already. Check it out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaly-foot_gastropod